# CSS border-property not working

Tags: html, css

```css
   .pagination-box ul{
     display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .pagination-box ul li{
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .pagination-box ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
     
     border :1px solid #cfcfcf;
     border-radius: 50%;
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     padding: 9px;
    
    }
    
    .pagination-box ul li.active{
     border:2px solid #ff9805;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row pagination-box hidden-xs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img ng-click="gotoPrev()" class="prev left-arrow" src="img/left_arrow.svg">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">01</li>
    <li class="">02</li>
    <li class="">03</li>
    <li class="">04</li>
    <li class="">05</li>
    <li class="">06</li>
    <li>
      <a>
        <img ng-click="gotoNext()" class="next right-arrow" src="img/right_arrow.svg">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

which looks like:

[image]

in the .active class I have specified a border property, but it is not working. However if I write `color:red;` or any other CSS property, it is working.

In chrome, when I inspect the element, it shows it like this:

[image]

I am not sure, why?

Comment: There is something that overrides your current style I guess

Comment: .pagination-box ul li.active{
    border:2px solid #ff9805 !important;
}

Comment: That's due the CSS specificity, your styles get overridden by the `:not()` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.pagination-box ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

This selector overrides your `.pagination-box ul li.active` (more specificity).

Soulution:

```
.pagination-box ul li.active {
  border:2px solid #ff9805 !important;
}
```

or:

```
.pagination-box ul li {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 9px;
}
.pagination-box ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child):not(.active) {
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}
.pagination-box ul li.active {
  border: 2px solid #ff9805;
}
```

or:

```
.pagination-box ul li.active:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border:2px solid #ff9805;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because the property is overrides by the property you applied for all li (i.e)

```
.pagination-box ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
   border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   padding: 9px;
}
```

You can overcome by specifying like this

```
.pagination-box ul li.active {
   border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/srcwwL2n/)

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Your styles get overridden by the `:not()` so you need to add !important to your active class

```
.pagination-box ul li.active{
    border:2px solid #ff9805 !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrw38xjz/

Answer (score 1):

your declaration

```
:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

is more specific than

```
.acitve
```

And css is using more specific declarations first. Here is some tutorial how this is count: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You may enter !important as someone already propose:

```
.pagination-box ul li.active{
    border:2px solid #ff9805 !important;
}
```

or specify the not attributes:

```
.pagination-box ul li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child).active{
    border:2px solid #ff9805;
}
```

so your active declaration will be more important

Answer (score 1):

If ever you do not want to use the !important, you can also extend the `:not` specificity with your additional `.active` class like this

```
.pagination-box ul li.active:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
    border:2px solid #ff9805;
}
```